# TypeError: load_road() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, faster-rcnn

These are the configurations. Do note that Image_Shape is [1024 1024 3]

```
Configurations:
BACKBONE_SHAPES                [[256 256]
 [128 128]
 [ 64  64]
 [ 32  32]
 [ 16  16]]
BACKBONE_STRIDES               [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
BATCH_SIZE                     1
BBOX_STD_DEV                   [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES        100
DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE       0.7
DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD        0.3
GPU_COUNT                      1
IMAGES_PER_GPU                 1
IMAGE_MAX_DIM                  1024
IMAGE_MIN_DIM                  800
IMAGE_PADDING                  True
IMAGE_SHAPE                    [1024 1024    3]
LEARNING_MOMENTUM              0.9
LEARNING_RATE                  0.002
MASK_POOL_SIZE                 14
MASK_SHAPE                     [28, 28]
MAX_GT_INSTANCES               100
MEAN_PIXEL                     [123.7 116.8 103.9]
MINI_MASK_SHAPE                (56, 56)
NAME                           road
NUM_CLASSES                    2
POOL_SIZE                      7
POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE        1000
POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING         2000
ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO             0.33
RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS              [0.5, 1, 2]
RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES              (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)
RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE              2
RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV               [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE    256
STEPS_PER_EPOCH                10
TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE           128
USE_MINI_MASK                  True
USE_RPN_ROIS                   True
VALIDATION_STPES               5
WEIGHT_DECAY                   0.0001
```

Here's a part of the entire code. I believe the error's due to the line  `def load_road(self, dataset_dir, subset):` but I'm not sure what it is and how to fix it.

```
class RoadDataset(utils.Dataset):

    def load_road(self, dataset_dir, subset):
        """Load a subset of the road dataset.
        dataset_dir: Root directory of the dataset.
        subset: Subset to load: train or val
        """
        # Add classes. We have only one class to add.
        self.add_class("sign", 1, "sign")

        # Train or validation dataset?
        assert subset in ["train", "val"]
        dataset_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, subset)

        # Load annotations
        # VGG Image Annotator (up to version 1.6) saves each image in the form:
        # { 'filename': '28503151_5b5b7ec140_b.jpg',
        #   'regions': {
        #       '0': {
        #           'region_attributes': {},
        #           'shape_attributes': {
        #               'all_points_x': [...],
        #               'all_points_y': [...],
        #               'name': 'polygon'}},
        #       ... more regions ...
        #   },
        #   'size': 100202
        # }
        # We mostly care about the x and y coordinates of each region
        # Note: In VIA 2.0, regions was changed from a dict to a list.
        annotations = json.load(open(os.path.join(dataset_dir, "via_region_data.json")))
        annotations = list(annotations.values())  # don't need the dict keys

        # The VIA tool saves images in the JSON even if they don't have any
        # annotations. Skip unannotated images.
        annotations = [a for a in annotations if a['regions']]

        # Add images
        for a in annotations:
            # Get the x, y coordinaets of points of the polygons that make up
            # the outline of each object instance. These are stores in the
            # shape_attributes (see json format above)
            # The if condition is needed to support VIA versions 1.x and 2.x.
            if type(a['regions']) is dict:
                polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions'].values()]
            else:
                polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions']] 

            # load_mask() needs the image size to convert polygons to masks.
            # Unfortunately, VIA doesn't include it in JSON, so we must read
            # the image. This is only managable since the dataset is tiny.
            image_path = os.path.join(dataset_dir, a['filename'])
            image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
            height, width = image.shape[:2]

            self.add_image(
                "road",
                image_id=a['filename'],  # use file name as a unique image id
                path=image_path,
                width=width, height=height,
                polygons=polygons)
            
    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        """Generate instance masks for an image.
       Returns:
        masks: A bool array of shape [height, width, instance count] with
            one mask per instance.
        class_ids: a 1D array of class IDs of the instance masks.
        """
        # If not a road dataset image, delegate to parent class.
        image_info = self.image_info[image_id]
        if image_info["source"] != "road":
            return super(self.__class__, self).load_mask(image_id)

        # Convert polygons to a bitmap mask of shape
        # [height, width, instance_count]
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        mask = np.zeros([info["height"], info["width"], len(info["polygons"])],
                        dtype=np.uint8)
        for i, p in enumerate(info["polygons"]):
            # Get indexes of pixels inside the polygon and set them to 1
            rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(p['all_points_y'], p['all_points_x'])
            mask[rr, cc, i] = 1

        # Return mask, and array of class IDs of each instance. Since we have
        # one class ID only, we return an array of 1s
        return mask.astype(np.bool), np.ones([mask.shape[-1]], dtype=np.int32)
    
    def image_reference(self, image_id):
        """Return the path of the image."""
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        if info["source"] == "road":
            return info["path"]
        else:
            super(self.__class__, self).image_reference(image_id)
```

Error that I'm encountering while running the train_shapes.ipynb on Karol Majek's implementation of the Mask_RCNN

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-308dc6a036cd> in <module>()
      3 # Training dataset.
      4 dataset_train = RoadDataset()
----> 5 dataset_train.load_road(18, config.IMAGE_SHAPE[0], config.IMAGE_SHAPE[1])
      6 dataset_train.prepare()
      7 

TypeError: load_road() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Comment: Not enough information to debug this. But one idea: does maybe `load_road` method accepts arguments like so: `dataset_train.load_road(18, config.IMAGE_SHAPE)`?

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I'm not entirely sure as I'm just running the files in Jupyter notebook to see how they work. But I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I tried out your suggestion. I'm receiving the same error. Would you like me to edit the question and provide the entire code instead?

Comment: Some part of code might be helpful. But you can't have the same error if you changed it as I said

Comment: can you just print `config.IMAGE_SHAPE[0]` and `config.IMAGE_SHAPE[0]` ?

Comment: @ErdalGENÇ it returns 1024, which is the IMAGE_MAX_DIM

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I've edited the question to include some more parts of the code that I think may be contributing to the error.

Comment: The function signature of load_road is `def load_road(self, dataset_dir, subset):`.  This means you can call it as `dataset_train.load_road(p1, p2)` where p1 is a path and p2 is  "train" or "eval".  Why are you calling with 3 parameters `18, config.IMAGE_SHAPE[0], config.IMAGE_SHAPE[1]` none of which are the desired type.

Comment: The error message basically says that you're calling the function with too many arguments - you're passing three but it should be only two (`self` is always an implicit argument on an instance method). But reading through the code it's obvious that the function `load_road` expects directory names as arguments, however you're passing numerical values to it. That doesn't seem to make any sense, so I'd suggest taking a step back and carefully going through your own code before you attempt to ask any further questions about it.

Comment: it's working now. As pointed out in the previous 2 comments, just had to change the arguments for the function